# Using the Axios CDN to display in Vue Template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vue-router

I want to display JSON information pulling from the Axios library. Using my `{{ id }}`, I want to call a certain param in the request.

I have an external **js file.**

```
const Home = { 
    template: `

    <div class="user">
        <h2>user {{ id }}</h2>
        bet
    </div>

    `,
    props: {
        id: {
            type:    String,
            default: 'N/A'
        }
    } 
}
```

CDN includes:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<script src="../../jobs/job.js"></script>
```

Router is fairly simple:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
        mode: 'history',
        routes: [
            {
                path: '/jobs/:id?',
                component: Home,
                props:     true
            },
        ],
    })
```

THANKS

Comment: How are you calling this `id` param currently? Please post some expected output.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear if ID is a property or a route parameter. I think you're using a route parameter here. If so, and you're not passing it into the component directly, then I think you can safely drop it and replace it with a computed property that will return the ID. Then simply add a `method` that will perform your axios request. And call that request in the `mounted` method of your component.

My thoughts are:

```
const Home = { 
  template: `

  <div class="user">
    <h2>user {{ id }}</h2>
    bet
  </div>

  `,
  mounted: function() {
    this.myRequest()
  }, 
  computed: {
    id: {
      get: function() {
        return this.$route.params.id
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    myRequest() {
      axios.get('/path/to/my/request', { params: { id: id }})
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response)
        }).catch(error => {
          console.log(response)
        })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am going to include the ID in ‘axios.get’ -> will try.

Comment: Getting a few errors @ohgodwhy - `myRequest is not defined` + `$route is not defined` + `"ReferenceError: $route is not defined"`

Comment: @BryanSanders Oops. Updated.